# how to show loading screen on php upload time?

Tags: php, mysql

i try to loading screen on php upload time, please help me

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","db_name");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
  $current_date = date("h:i:sa");
  $date_title = "TODAY";     
  $update_query1 = "insert into date(date_title, date) values('$date_title', '$current_date')";
  if(mysqli_query($con,$update_query1)){
  echo "<script>alert('Comments has been published')</script>";
  echo "<script>window.open('load.php','_self')</script>";
 }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question at all and how your code relates to that.

Comment: this code process to data insert to database,

Comment: how to show "please wait" word, inserting time

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code to show loader during submit the data

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return showoverlay();">
    <div id="overlay" hidden>
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin spin-big"></i>
    </div>
    Your HTML Design Code here.
</form>

<script>
    function showoverlay() {
       $('#overlay').prop('hidden',false);
       $('#overlay').css({"display": "table"});
    }
</script>
```

May be this code is useful to you.

Comment: You need to have JQuery library if you are wondering why this code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The moment user clicks the upload button, display `Loading...` in the screen. Once upload is successful change `Loading...` to `Success`.

Use AJAX.

Comment: @thiyagarajan Sorry, I'm not an expert just learning through my hobby project. Just giving a hint, as I have thought, keep a `<span>` to display msg on the screen, use a `onclick` tag in the upload button to refer to the JS function and deliver the loading msg to the span. Once upload is successful deliver success msg to the span. Just search here you will get many upload script. Modify them as per your requirment.